# Golong (gorm) - how to create new record with json

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm trying to create simple backend RestAPI with golang, gin, gorm. I'm a little bit lost here.
I want to create a new record on DB with below payload
Please refer below code

This is my sample payload getting from frontend - React

```
{
    "logged_user": {
        "user_id": "2350e6aa-ee3d-11eb-8d84-1e00d1365135",
        "full_name": "demo1",
        "email": "sample@gmail.com",
        "role": "admin"
    },
    "employee_detail": [
        {
            "from_address": "chennai-102",
            "to_address": "chennai-17",
            "emp_id": "071bdd76-0b36-11ed-9a05-0242ac130003",
            "emp_date": "07/29/2021",
            "reason": "dinner",
            "comments": "this is comments field ponnamalle"
        },
 {
            "from_address": "chennai-102",
            "to_address": "chennai-17",
            "emp_id": "071bdd76-0b36-11ed-9a05-0242ac13000",
            "emp_date": "07/29/2021",
            "reason": "dinner",
            "comments": "this is comments field"
        },
        ]
    
}
```

This is emp model, i've create base type for generating UUID
Model.go

```
type Base struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID string `gorm:"primary_key;not_null" json:"id"`
}

type Emp struct {
    Base
    LoggedUser LoggedUser `gorm:"embedded" json:"logged_user"`
    EmpDetail []struct {
        EmpId      string  `gorm:"not_null;" json:"Emp_id"`
        Date    string  `gorm:"size:255;not_null;" json:"date"`
        FromAddress string  `gorm:"size:255;not_null;" json:"from_address"`
        ToAddress   string  `gorm:"size:255;not_null;" json:"to_address"`
        Reason      string  `gorm:"size:255;not_null;" json:"reason"`
        Comments    string  `gorm:"size:255;not_null;" json:"comments"`
    } `gorm:"foreignKey:TripId;" json:"emp_detail"`
}
```

CreateEmp for Unmarshall the bdoy and prepare for bodyto saveEmp

controller.go

```
func (server *Server) CreateEmp(context *gin.Context) {
    errMessage := map[string]string{}
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(context.Request.Body)
    var emp models.Emp

    if err != nil {
        errMessage["Invalid Request"] = "Invalid Request"
        context.JSON(http.StatusUnprocessableEntity, gin.H{
            "status": http.StatusUnprocessableEntity,
            "error":  errMessage,
        })
        return
    }

    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &emp)
    if err != nil {
        errMessage["Unable to Unmarshall"] = "Unable to unmarshal"
        context.JSON(http.StatusUnprocessableEntity, gin.H{
            "status": http.StatusUnprocessableEntity,
            "error":  errMessage,
        })
        return
    }

    createdEmp, err := emp.SaveEmp(server.DB)

    if err != nil {
        context.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
            "status": http.StatusInternalServerError,
            "error":  err.Error(),
        })
        return
    }

    context.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
        "status":   http.StatusOK,
        "response": createdEmp,
    })

}
```

Finally save method for create record to DB.
saveEmp Method

```
func (emp *Emp) SaveEmp(db *gorm.DB) (*Emp, error) {
    if err := db.Debug().Create(&emp).Error; err != nil {
       return &Emp{}, err
}
return emp, nil
}
```

with the above code when i am trying to create new record. it's create empty record with loggedUser field alone. please refer below image
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you trying to embed the logged in user information in employee table column? because the `embedded` tag this is what it does. By your screenshot I see that you have a different table for logged in user details.

Comment: Thanks @SpirosI.Economakis. 
yes i want to stored logged in user information in employee table. And the above screenshot is actually employee table.

Comment: Now I am a bit confused. If this is the employee table where are the `from_address `, `to_address` etc. fields and you miss the `logged_user` field which will hold the embedded data.

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, i suggest you to separate business logic from database logic. try reading this code in 2 weeks and you will go crazy.Take a look [repository pattern](https://threedots.tech/post/repository-pattern-in-go/).

If i were you, i'll make a singleton to handle connection with DB and use [gorm Migrartion](https://gorm.io/docs/migration.html) to keep your schema DB updated.

Then, make EmpDetails a type, migrate both of entities

The result is something like

```
type Emp struct{
gorm.Model
//other fields
EmpDet []*EmpDetails `gorm:"foreignKey:emp_id;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE" json:"details"`
}

type EmpDetails{
    gorm.Model
    //other fields
    EmpID *uint `json:"EmpId" gorm:"column:emp_id"`
    Emp *Emp `gorm:"foreignKey:emp_id;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:SET NULL"`
}
```

Be careful gorm tags, specially with foreignKey naming. Take a look [gorm has many association](https://gorm.io/docs/has_many.html)
Also, i notice that some tags don't work without a pointer to the field